# iPhone OS 4.0.x - transition from background to foreground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multitasking

iPhone programming question:

Is it possible to wakeup/resume iPhone application from background mode to foreground mode programmatically?

I have a long-running background task, which is being launched in applicationDidEnterBackground method of UIApplicationDelegate.

I need to make my application active/visible using some code inside this background task.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. However, you can fire a local notification to alert the user.