# Bring application to foreground during call

Tags: ios, phone-call

I wanted to bring my application to the foreground during a phone call. I know I have this 
`call.callState==CTCallStateConnected` but I wanted to  run some commands when a call state is considered active.

So when a phone call is detected (connected state), I want my application to popup from the background and appear in the foreground. I’m just not sure how to get the application to register that `CallConnectedState` when running in the background (and reopen once that is activated?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael is correct, but I just wanted to add that this is not possible in any iOS version, which includes iOS 5. You simply cannot force your app to the foreground when a phone call is active.

There may be some way to accomplish this with a jailbroken phone, but I have no idea how. That is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: what about a popup message? or reopen my application on ending of a call?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% certain about iOS 5, but under iOS 4.X you certainly could ***not*** programatically force an app from background back into the foreground.

Apple's philosophy is that the user is in control at all times and whatever app s/he wants to be in the foreground stays in the foreground.

Here's [another question that has the roughly the same question as you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419559/iphone-os-4-0-x-transition-from-background-to-foreground).

Comment: so a popup message then to have them go back to the application?

Comment: [Here is another thread on the same subject](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1038686.html), which suggests you can use local notifications.  [Here is one tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/) for that [and another one](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/local-push-notification-sample-code-os.html).